How can I add a ground conductor to outside GFI outlets?
I have 3 GFI outlets in and around my garden, they all are showing an open ground. Can I fix this by putting in a grounding rod and grounding them to that?

The first question is why. Were they installed with cable having no grounding conductor? Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

No, but you don't need to, either
A GFCI outlet without a grounding wire coming to it simply needs to be labeled "NO EQUIPMENT GROUND", as a GFCI suffices as a substitute for equipment grounding in a retrofit scenario.  See NEC 406.4(D)(2)(b) and (c) for the details.
(A grounding rod is only good for returning errant natural electricity to nature.  It doesn't help return fault current back to the utility.)
